# Is it possible to get the <a href> in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm actually trying to find a way to get the href in my website url because i want to change the typo color regarding this href,  but i can't find how to do it.

For example, if i have the URL 
`http://localhost/website/?date=2019#Presse`

I would like to get the "Presse"

Here is my code :

```
<div class=" col-sm-3 col-12">
    <div class = "row">

        <div class="col-12"><a  class = "<?php //php code to get the href ?>" href="#Distinctions">Distinctions</a></div>

        <div class="col-12"> <a class = "<?php //php code to get the href ?>" href="#Presse">Presse</a></div>

        <div class="col-12"> <a class = "<?php //php code to get the href ?>" href="#Expositions">Expositions</a></div>

        <div class="col-12"><a class = "<?php //php code to get the href ?>" href="#Conférences">Conférences</a><br/><br/></div>
```

Is it possible to get this in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Looking at you example, I get the feeling you're attempting to use PHP like JavaScript, client-side, which it isn't, so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this,hope it helps

```
echo $str=explode("#","http://localhost/website/?date=2019#Presse")[1];
//output Presse
```

Comment: Can you explain **why** one should try that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?php
$url = "Thttp://localhost/website/?date=2019#Presse";
$presse = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);

echo $presse;
?>
```

I have used `parse_url`. This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present. The values of the array elements are not URL decoded.
 **PHP_URL_FRAGMENT** to retrieve just a specific URL component. For more info, you can visit [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
Here is the live [demo](https://3v4l.org/rdYHm)

Answer (score 0):

You should get url parameter
then explode to split date and string then use your string as class
Try this code

```
class="<?php if (isset($_GET['date'])) {  $string=explode('#',$_GET['date']); echo $string[1]; } else { echo 'red'; }" ?>
```

Comment: this could be improved with a ternary statement - much better use of inline PHP

Comment: example: `<?php echo ($foo == 'bar' ? 'conditional is met' : 'conditional is not met'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="<?php //php code to get the href ?>#Distinctions" class="classname">Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers.
I'm sorry, but i think i have not been clear in my question : i have to get the full url first because the #id can change. It can end by #Presse or by #Distinctions for example (or i just did not understand your answers, thats possible too :) )

But i don't know why, i had an "illumination", and i did it in JS (it's working) :

```
  function changeBold(name)
{
    document.getElementById(name).className = "navigationB";
    if(name != 'Distinctions')   document.getElementById('Distinctions').className = "navigation";
    if(name != 'Presse')   document.getElementById('Presse').className = "navigation";
    if(name != 'Expositions')   document.getElementById('Expositions').className = "navigation";
    if(name != 'Conférences')   document.getElementById('Conférences').className = "navigation";
}
```